# Extract list from given list and given indices

Tags: python, list

I have a list containinig, more or less, random values. The list always has a fixed length.
I have another list containing integer values. These values are always smaller than the length of the first list.

I want to calculate a list containing all values from the first list whose indices are described by the values in the second list.
I came up with the following:

```
>>> values = ['000', '111', '222', '333', '444', '555', '666', '777']
>>> indices = [2, 4, 7]
>>> [v for i, v in enumerate(values) if i in indices]
['222', '444', '777']
```

As my lists are rather small (24 elements) this is OK for me. Anyway, I wonder if there is some more elegant solution which does not calculate a temporary list (with `enumerate()`).

Comment: *which does not calculate a temporary list (with `enumerate()`)* - `enumerate` doesn't create a temporary list.

Comment: Hm, you're right, it returns an iterator, even in python2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> values = ['000', '111', '222', '333', '444', '555', '666', '777']
>>> indices = [2, 4, 7]
```

1. You can use a simple list comprehension

   ```
   >>> [values[index] for index in indices]
   ['222', '444', '777']
   ```
2. You can use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), like this

   ```
   >>> from operator import itemgetter
   >>> itemgetter(*indices)(values)
   ('222', '444', '777')
   >>> list(itemgetter(*indices)(values))
   ['222', '444', '777']
   ```
3. Or you can invoke the magic method, `__getitem__` with `map`, like this

   ```
   >>> map(values.__getitem__, indices)
   ['222', '444', '777']
   ```

   If you are using Python 3.x, then you might want to use `list` with `map`

   ```
   >>> list(map(values.__getitem__, indices))
   ['222', '444', '777']
   ```
4. If you don't want to create the entire list, then you can create a generator expression and use `next` with that to get the values whenever you want.

   ```
   >>> filtered = (values[index] for index in indices)
   >>> next(filtered)
   '222'
   >>> next(filtered)
   '444'
   >>> next(filtered)
   '777'
   >>> next(filtered)
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
   StopIteration
   ```

   If you are going to just iterate the result, then I would recommend using the generator expression approach.

   ```
   >>> for item in (values[index] for index in indices):
   ...     print(item + ' ' + item)
   ...     
   222 222
   444 444
   777 777
   ```